# Cannot finish dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

So I have spent a lot of time on this and have got to the final part and cannot seem to make my dropdown function.

I am using jQuery hover. Hover over main link, sub links appear and the content moves down, hover over a sublink that has children and the sub sublinks appear and the content moves down some more but when I get to hover over a sub sub link, my content shifts back up but the sub sub links remain visible under it.

I have a few theories that may help me get through this, one of which is to use a sub function instead of two different ones. Another is to use a case statement to move the content but I have a feeling that if I streamline my code I may end up fixing the problem also.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main-menu-link").hover(function () {
        $(".main-menu-link").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        //$(".menu-depth-1").hide();
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').hide();
        //
        $(this).siblings(".menu-depth-1").fadeIn();
        if ($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible")) {
            $("#index-content").animate({
                'margin-top': 46
            });
            alert('doh');
        } else {
            $("#index-content").animate({
                'margin-top': 10
            });
        }

    });
    $(".sub-menu-link").hover(function () {
        $(".sub-menu-link").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').hide();
        $(this).siblings(".menu-depth-2").fadeIn();
        if ($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible")) {
            $("#index-content").animate({
                'margin-top': 92
            });
        } else {
            $("#index-content").animate({
                'margin-top': 46
            });
        }
    });

});
```

and here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8tcQT/4/

Thanks for any help and thanks for reading.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".sub-menu-link").hover(function () {
```

This line is the reason why *sub-sub-links* cause the content to move up, because both *sub-links* and *sub-sub-links* trigger that hover function.

```
$(".sub-menu-link").hover(function () {
    $(".sub-menu-link").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    // I added the following line:
    $(this).siblings().find('.sub-menu-link').off('mouseenter mouseleave');

    $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').hide();
    $(this).siblings(".menu-depth-2").fadeIn();
    if ($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible")) {
        $("#index-content").animate({
            'margin-top': 92
        });
    } else {
        $("#index-content").animate({
            'margin-top': 46
        });
    }
});
```

With the line of code added, it removes the hover function from *sub-sub-links* when their parent *sub-links* are first hovered.

Alternatively, use another class name instead of `class="sub-menu-link"` for *sub-sub-links*.

Note that my solution only tackles the problem found at the level of *sub-sub-links*. If there is a need for even deeper lists of links i.e. *sub-sub-sub-links* and *sub-sub-sub-sub-links*, creating a "sub function", as you said, will be preferable.